# Sending gzip compressed data through TCP socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets, http, get, bzip

I'm creating an HTTP server in Python without any of the HTTP libraries for learning purposes. Right now it can serve static files fine.

The way I serve the file is through this piece of code:

```
with open(self.filename, 'rb') as f:
    src = f.read()
socket.sendall(src)
```

However, I want to optimize its performance a bit by sending compressed data instead of uncompressed. I know that my browser (Chrome) accepts compressed data because it tells me in the header

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
```

So, I changed my code to this

```
with open(self.filename, 'rb') as f:
    src = zlib.compress(f.read())
socket.sendall(src)
```

But this just outputs garbage. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you send the appropriate `Content-Encoding=gzip` header?

Comment: Yes, I have. The data I'm returning in a GET request is headers followed by 2 CRLFs followed by compressed body. This outputs garbage. If I compress everything (this includes the headers) then my browser downloads the file instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The zlib library implements the deflate compression algorithm (RFC 1951). There are two encapsulations for the deflate compression: zlib (RFC 1950) and gzip (RFC 1952). These differ only in the kind of header and trailer they provide around the deflate compressed data.

`zlib.compress` only provides the raw deflate data, without any header and trailer. To get these you need to use a compression object. For gzip this looks like this:

```
z = zlib.compressobj(-1,zlib.DEFLATED,31)
gzip_compressed_data = z.compress(data) + z.flush()
```

The important part here is the `31` as the 3rd argument to `compressobj`. This specifies gzip format which then can be used with `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!